# Conditional Styling latex on items

Tags: beamer, conditionals

I am trying to create an agenda (headlines) frame for my presentation slides.
I am reducing redundancy, and define the itemized frame once, and reuse it. But each time, i want a different item in the list, to be emboldened or highlighted.

I have managed that in the following way: I define a command, and reuse it, by giving a parameter.

Definition:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\ifnum #1=1
    \item \textbf{Introduction}
\else 
    \item Introduction
\fi
\ifnum #1=2
    \item \textbf{Research Questions}
\else 
    \item Research Questions
\fi
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Use:

```
\agenda{1}
# the intro slides ...
\agenda{2}
# the R.Q. slides ...
# \agenda{3}...
```

The problem is that this method is also redundant. Each header is written twice. Is there a more efficient way to set the Bold style (or any style) based on the number parameter?
(Since I do not know how to accurately phrase the question, i understand that this might have a duplicate question)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{Research Questions}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{Summary}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `alert` for this purpose.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=gray,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black,bg=} %color
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries} %bold
\usebeamercolor{normal text}
\begin{itemize}[<alert@+>]
  \item Introduction
  \item Research Questions
  \item Other things
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Edit: code modified as suggested by @samcarter.

Comment: You could simply the code a bit by using `\begin{itemize}[<alert@+>]`, then you would not have to repeat `\alert<+>{}` for each item. I would suggest to use `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` instead of `\frame{}`, this syntax only works because of legacy reasons.

Comment: @samcarter Done. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: You're welcome! I removed some unnecessary `{}`, please feel free to roll back my edit if you don't like.